# Getting the length of an audio asset?

Tags: assets

I'm trying to create a podcast feed with Craft, and I seem to have everything working... except I can't find out how to grab the length of an audio file dynamically. I can get the filesize in bytes, and if it's an image asset you can get width... but there doesn't seem to be a way to get the play-time for an audio file; which is needed for the <itunes:duration> tag.

Anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Craft doesn't come with a PHP library for audio, so there's no core solution for your problem.

But what you could do is to make a plugin, add such a library to it and provide `duration` and `bitrate` Twig filters to your templates.

**EDIT:**

You could try out my new ["Asset Metadata"](https://github.com/carlcs/craft-assetmetadata) plugin. It makes use of the [getID3](https://github.com/JamesHeinrich/getID3/) PHP library to extract all sort of metadata from your assets.

To make your life a bit easier, I added further beautified metadata properties like a sound file's playtime duration in ISO 8601 date interval format (i.e. `PT1H21M48S`), or a photo's exposure time as a ratio.